# Twitterizer: what is the workflow in order to publish messages on user's profile?

Tags: message, token, publish, twitterizer

as I started to work with Twitterizer in order to publish on someone's wall I am in confusing time.
There is a page, my case, DefaultTwitter.aspx where is link to authenticate on twitter with token provided. Goes on Twitter and comes back to CallbackTwitter.aspx with outh_token and secret. And so the user is identified. On twitterizer example says:

*Step 5 - Store the results
            You should now store the access token and the user details. Keep in mind that the
            only way an access token will become invalid is if the user revokes access by logging
            into Twitter. Otherwise, those values will grant you access to that user's data
            forever.*

**My questions are:** - should I store any data in SQL datatable and what exactly(however I hope that is not the case to do so)

- somebody said that I should save in a cookie(I thought in session); however then if another user comes then how should I create a button to logout or something like that?

-how will user revoke application access if he would like so?

A live example will be much appreciated as I could not found any on internet how exactly twitter api works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your application finishes getting authorization to access the user's data, the result is the access token (represented by 2 values, a key and a secret). Those values are, in effect, the username/password you can use in requests to the API on behalf of that user.* Save those values in your SQL database. You'll also be given the user id and screen name. It's probably a good idea to keep those handy, too.

The user can revoke access to an application by going to http://twitter.com/settings/applications, finding the application and clicking the revoke access button next to it. Your application cannot revoke access for the user.

You asked for an example, but you're citing the example application. Just look at the source code in that sample.

* - That's a simplification for explanation sake. Please don't crucify me, OAuth experts.

Comment: thanks Ricky for your answer, but I have a question: how I am going to know when a certain user comes to my site and so I can make connection with his twitter account? I don't want to make a connection between a user ID from my application and a twitter user id. He might want to use more twitter accounts...Otherwise I might ask for my user to authenticate with twitter each time he wants to publish something...

Comment: It sounds like your application will need to maintain its own register/login functionality. You could then remember multiple sets of access tokens for each user, then ask them to select the account they wish to use, if they have added more than one. Since I don't know anything about the application you're making, I can't be very precise in my suggestion.

Comment: let's say i am gone a save related user information for twitter. What happens if a user is logged in my application but not on twitter. Shall the message be published?

Comment: If you have an access token, then the user does not need to be logged in to twitter. Your application would be acting on the user's behalf, so the user doesn't even have to be logged in to your application.

Comment: I see, it is very much different comparing with facebook api oauth 2.0; all right thanks for your answer, on monday I will implement this, after I am done and working I will mark as answered ;)

Comment: It shouldn't be that different. The goal of OAuth is to provide an application the means to access a user's data: an access token.